# Check GraphVIZ installed version on Ubuntu

Tags: graphviz

How to check the version of GraphViz installed on my UBUNTU(12.04) laptop?
What command is used to find the version?
dot -V is the correct one?

Answer (score 28):

```
$ dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.36.0 (20140111.2315)
```

I would think so since thats what I get on running the command .

Answer (score 1):

This does it for me
`$ dpkg -l | grep graphviz`